# what resolution was selected in create new document settings dialog

Tags: resolution, dpi, adobe-illustrator

i created designed a flyer few days back in adobe illustrator cs6
i am not confirmed whether i created it at 72 dpi or 300 dpi

how can i check if the document was created at 72dpi or 300dpi.

I am not asking about changing image resolution.

I am asking about changing document resolution ??

The resolution option which is selected when we select create new document option.

By selecting the Edit Artboard option, i can only edit the dimensions (w x h)

but i am not able to find anywhere how to check what was the resolution selected in the create new document settings dialog.

vineet

Answer (score 0):

Menu - Effects - Document Raster Effect Settings...

Comment: If this solution is OK for you, please do not forget to mark me answer as useful